# How to revert to android 7 on Xiaomi A1 phone

Tags: xiaomi, mi-a1

The phone has some bugs in this new update I have tried doing a factory reset but it still has the android 8.

Comment: A factory reset never reverts system updates. Take a look at our [factory-reset tag-wiki](/tags/factory-reset/info) for details. So as Gastón wrote, you'll need to download and flash an Android-7 ROM that was build for your device if you want to downgrade.

Comment: Also is it possible that with this new update can cause sound issues with the receiver since I am not hearing anything when someone calls me. I have run the android diagnostic to check to see if the receiver is working and it failed that test. If I revert back to Android 7 might it fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It applies the same concept as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06rlFAwGJYM

you will need to download the ROM of android 7 and flash the device

its an easy process that take less than 5 minutes